# Load Jenkins shared library from a local directory path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Context:** Jenkins currently allows following retrievers for shared libraries, (according to [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-groovy-lib/#library-load-a-library-on-the-fly:%7E:text=including%20the%20changes.-,retriever,-(optional)))

- http
- nexus
- legacySCM
- modernSCM

They all require some way of packaging before allowed to be retrieved to be loaded into the pipeline runtime environment. The problem is when we need to continuously test the shared library it becomes extremely tedious to continuously package/'scm commit' every time a change is made and we need to test.

If we had a way to load the shared library from a local directory in the same host as where the Jenkins instance is running. We'll be able to mount that directory to our development workspace directory, do changes and trigger the pipeline runs through the Jenkins APIs continuously, allowing us to seamlessly test.

**Question:**
How do we achieve the loading of a shared library from a local directory path?

**Postscript:**
Furthermore, I believe that all of the above mentioned retrievers retrieve the files and put them to a directory, so that Jenkins can access them. So in this case, we wouldn't need the retrievers but to tell Jenkins to access the given directory path instead of the default/current one.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve local loading is to use modernSCM and the git `file:///` url.

You just need to point to `file:///c:/your/local/repo/path/root` and it will get loaded. Of course you need to point to an existing branch and your changes need to be committed but it works great. I personally rely on this loop for my shared libs development :

- dev + dummy commit
- local test
- dev + dummy commit
- local test
- git soft reset + git final commit + git push